# How to extract multiple postal codes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to extract multiple postal `codes` and `place names` from the following text but I'm not sure how.

```
Great World
1 Kim Seng Promenade, Great World, #01-138, Singapore 237994
(Nearest Drop Off at Office Lobby)
+65 6737 1366
Jem
50 Jurong Gateway Road #02-07 Singapore 608549
+65 6694 1161
Jewel Changi Airport
80 Airport Boulevard, Jewel Changi Airport,
#03-214, Singapore 819666
+65 6241 3353
Junction 8 Shopping Centre
9 Bishan Place #01-41 Singapore 579837
+65 6356 5228
Jurong Point Shopping Centre
63 Jurong West Central 3 #B1-68
Singapore 648331
+65 6861 1811
```

This is what I have so far but it only extracts `one` postal code instead of multiple postal codes. I am also having trouble extracting the place name just before the address but I'm not sure how. Can someone assist me in this? Thanks!

```
        var singAddrArray = [];// 
        var extractPostalRegex = "\\s\\s\\b\\d{6}\\b|Singapore\\s+\\d{6}";
        var postal = text.match(extractPostalRegex);
        postal, result = postal[0].toString().replace(/[a-zA-Z]+\s+/g,'');
        var sixDigitRegex = "\\b\\d{6}\\b";

        if (result.match(sixDigitRegex)) {
          singAddrArray.push(result);
          console.log(singAddrArray);
          console.log('sing address match!');
        } else {
          console.log('no matches found!');
        }
```

Comment: So, what you're looking for is _always_ a place name followed by a postal code? Are the postal codes _always_ 6 digits?

Comment: In the code snippet, the variable "text" stores the entire text stated above it, correct?

Comment: Yes correct! Im using a boilerplate to extract the text. Currently, what you are seeing is just the simplified text where the noises are reduced to solve this problem.

Comment: Please answer my questions...

Comment: @AnujPancholi Yes you're right!

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes you got it.

Comment: And the city names can contain only letters (and spaces?)

Comment: @Cerbrus bingo!

Comment: Perhaps `[^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*\s+\d{6}\b` https://regex101.com/r/9r3yyG/1 if there are no digits in the city names

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for your help. I really appreciate it, but how do i extract all of the postal values from the text using the given expression?

Comment: @scorezel789 You could use a capturing group. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negated character class to match word chars without matching an underscore to match a city name followed by repeating that 0+ times preceded by a space.

If you want to get the 6 digits, you could use a capturing group.

Then match the 6 digits.

```
([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)\s+(\d{6})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\W\d]+` Match a word char except digits
  - `(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a word char without digits preceded by 1+ whitespac chars
- `)` Close group
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d{6}` Match 6 digits
- `)\b` Close group followed by a word bounary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSWV52/1)

```js
let str = `Great World
1 Kim Seng Promenade, Great World, #01-138, Singapore 237994
(Nearest Drop Off at Office Lobby)
+65 6737 1366
Jem
50 Jurong Gateway Road #02-07 Singapore 608549
+65 6694 1161
Jewel Changi Airport
80 Airport Boulevard, Jewel Changi Airport,
#03-214, Singapore 819666
+65 6241 3353
Junction 8 Shopping Centre
9 Bishan Place #01-41 Singapore 579837
+65 6356 5228
Jurong Point Shopping Centre
63 Jurong West Central 3 #B1-68
Singapore 648331
+65 6861 1811`;

const regex = /([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)\s+(\d{6})\b/g;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log("Full match: " + m[0]);
  console.log("City: " + m[1]);
  console.log("Postal code: " + m[2]);
  console.log("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply (: Im sorry i dont get you can you give an example?

Comment: @scorezel789 I have added a Javascript example to the answer. The full match is in `m[0]`, the value of the capturing group is in `m[1]`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is really helpful in understanding what you're trying to do. i did a while loop earlier but i ended up in an inifinite loop. Im going to give this answer a thumbs up.

Comment: Im sorry is there by any chance you could help in retrieving the `place name` just before the address? If its quite some work its fine i will figure out..

Comment: @scorezel789 Sure, in that case you could use 2 capturing groups instead of 1.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that city names and postal codes are rather predictable in their format, this should do the trick:

```js
const text = `Great World
1 Kim Seng Promenade, Great World, #01-138, Singapore 237994
(Nearest Drop Off at Office Lobby)
+65 6737 1366
Jem
50 Jurong Gateway Road #02-07 Singapore 608549
+65 6694 1161
Jewel Changi Airport
80 Airport Boulevard, Jewel Changi Airport,
#03-214, Singapore 819666
+65 6241 3353
Junction 8 Shopping Centre
9 Bishan Place #01-41 Singapore 579837
+65 6356 5228
Jurong Point Shopping Centre
63 Jurong West Central 3 #B1-68
Singapore 648331
+65 6861 1811`;

const results = text.match(/([a-z ]+)(\d{6})/gi);
console.log(results.map(r => r.trim()))
```

Comment: You make look so simple and clean. I didnt thought of using map. Thanks for your help! (:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want "Singapore " or just the codes, so I did both:

```js
const text = `Great World
1 Kim Seng Promenade, Great World, #01-138, Singapore 237994
(Nearest Drop Off at Office Lobby)
+65 6737 1366
Jem
50 Jurong Gateway Road #02-07 Singapore 608549
+65 6694 1161
Jewel Changi Airport
80 Airport Boulevard, Jewel Changi Airport,
#03-214, Singapore 819666
+65 6241 3353
Junction 8 Shopping Centre
9 Bishan Place #01-41 Singapore 579837
+65 6356 5228
Jurong Point Shopping Centre
63 Jurong West Central 3 #B1-68
Singapore 648331
+65 6861 1811`

var extractPostalRegex = /\s\s\b\d{6}\b|Singapore\s+\d{6}/g
var postal = text.match(extractPostalRegex);
console.log(`Singapore and codes:\n`,postal);
const postalCodes = postal.reduce((codes,matchedString) => {
 let codeMatch = matchedString.match(/\d{6}/);
 if(codeMatch){
  codes.push(codeMatch[0]);
 }
 return codes;
},[]);
console.log(`ONLY codes`,postalCodes);
```

The first regex I used is exactly the one you did, but I added a 'g' flag in the end. That stands for "global", supported by javascript, which returns **all** the matches from a given string, instead of only the **first** match using the **greedy** approach that javascript uses by default.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate the help and effort you're putting in to provide the code as well as explaining what the regex does. I did'nt know about the greedy approach using regex. I only wanted the six digit codes. But regardless both looks great! Thanks!!